# Why won't it break?

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, break

So I'm working on a piece of code i was given as an assignment. I'm having trouble with the second else part of code. When the input is odd, it goes to this part of code and won't break when the loop restarts. I know there is a flaw in this part and was wondering if any one could help me see it. (Sorry if this code seems very amateur, I am learning.

I've tried changing the location for the input but to no avail.

def part1c():

```
    def get_int(prompt):
            while True:
                    try:
                            return int(butt(prompt))
                    except ValueError:
                            pass

    def get_ch(prompt):
            while True:
                    res = butt(prompt).strip()
                    if res:
                            return res[:1]


    def make_row(w , edge, center):
            return edge*(w>0) + center*(w-2) + edge*(w>1)

    import time

    def print_rectangle(h, w, c):
            top_row = make_row(w, c, c)
            mid_row = make_row(w, c, ' ')
            rows = [top_row]*(h>0) + [mid_row]*(h-2) + [top_row]*(h>1)
            print('\n'.join(rows))
            while True:
                    print_rectangle(h, w, c)
                    time.sleep(2)



    def main():
            h = get_int('Size of box in rows? ')
            w = get_int('Size of box in columns? ')
            c = get_ch('Character to use: ')
            print_rectangle(h, w, c)

    while True:
            print('Draw boxes:(Enter 0 to stop)')
            butt=int(input('If box has an odd number(s), type it.' +
                     ' If not, type the even number(s):') )
            if butt == 0:
                    print('Thank you, next')
                    break
            else:

                    if butt % 2== 0:
                            pass


                            rows=int(input('Size of box in rows? '))
                            cols= int(input('Size of box in columns? '))
                            for r in range(rows):
                                    for c in range(cols):
                                            print('*', end='')
                                    print()

                    else:
                            butt_is_zero = True
                            while butt_is_zero:
                                    import sys

                                    # Python 2/3 compatibility shims
                                    if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000:
                                        butt = input
                                        rng = range
                                    else:
                                        butt = raw_input
                                        rng = xrange


                                    if __name__=="__main__":
                                            main()
                                    if butt==1:
                                            butt_is_zero = False

                                    get_int()
                                    get_ch()
                                    make_row()
                                    print_rectangle()
                                    part1c()
```

part1c()

Comment: Don't define functions in loops

Comment: That fixed it , didn't think it would! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one thing your can try is change

```
  else:
      while True:
          import sys
```

to

```
  else:
      butt_is_zero = True
      while butt_is_zero:
          import sys
```

then to break the while loop

```
      if butt==1:
          butt_is_zero = False
```

Also the message above ^^ dont define functions inside of a loop instead place them outside of the loop and call them as needed.

ex

```
import time    

def print_rectangle(h, w, c):
    top_row = make_row(w, c, c)
    mid_row = make_row(w, c, ' ')
    rows = [top_row]*(h>0) + [mid_row]*(h-2) + [top_row]*(h>1)
    print('\n'.join(rows))




while True:

    print_rectangle(h, w, c)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: So i've tried this, and have put the functions out of the loop, although the time import only has the final result print the same box infinite times and the loop won't break still. I've updated the code. Again, thank you. I'd give you more awesome sauce if you could help me find something wrong with it again.